# How to write unit test case and Mock SmtpClient Send mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nunit, smtpclient

````
I am writing unit test case for the below class Communication service. I have the below interface communicationservice .
I want to write the Nunit or unit test for the SendMail method which is present in the CommunicationService without sending mails. (smtpClient.Send(mailMessage))


```
public interface ISmtpClient
    {
        void Send(MailMessage message);
    }

    public class SmtpClientWrapper : ISmtpClient
    {
        public SmtpClientWrapper(SmtpClient client)
        {
            Client = client;
        }

        public SmtpClient Client { get; }

        public void Send(MailMessage message)
        {
            Client.Send(message);
        }
    }
    public interface ICommunicationService
    {
        bool SendMail(string mailSender, IEnumerable<string> recipients, IEnumerable<string> cc, string subject, string mailContent, string senderPass);
    }
````

Implementation logic for the communication service parameter here are the details needed for Mail message class. for send mail
public class CommunicationService : ICommunicationService
{
private readonly ILogger _logger;
private readonly ISmtpClient _client;
public CommunicationService(
ILogger logger, ISmtpClient client)
{
_logger = logger;
_client = client;
// also read appsettings for the smtp client details
}
public bool SendMail(string mailSender, IEnumerable recipients, IEnumerable cc, string subject, string mailContent, string senderPass)
{
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage
{
Subject = subject,
Body = mailContent,
From = new MailAddress(mailSender, "XXXX"),
IsBodyHtml = true
};

```
            var recipientsList = recipients.ToList();
            if (!recipientsList.Any())
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Mail not sent, no recipients specified");
            }

            foreach (var address in recipientsList)
            {
                mailMessage.To.Add(address);
            }

            if (cc != null)
            {
                foreach (string address in cc)
                {
                    mailMessage.CC.Add(address);
                }
            }
            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(mailSender, senderPass);


            try
            {

                var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "smtp.office365.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = networkCredential,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    Timeout = 20000,

                };
                var wrapper = new SmtpClientWrapper(smtp);

                smtp.Send(mailMessage);

                return true;
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                _logger.LogError(exception.Message, exception);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
From the consumer i call the communication service send method with the details needed for Mail message.Passing here the parameters needed for MailMessage class



here is the code i have tried. Here is the unit test case 



    public void SendMail_SuccessfullySendsMail_ReturnsTrue()
        {
           
            // Arrange
           
            var mailSender = "your-email@example.com";
            var recipients = new List<string> { "recipient1@example.com", "recipient2@example.com" };
            var cc = new List<string> { "cc1@example.com", "cc2@example.com" };
            var subject = "Test Subject";
            var mailContent = "Test Body";
            var senderPass = "your-password";
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()
            {
                Body = "ABC",
                Subject = subject

            };
            var clientMock = new Mock<ISmtpClient>();
           // clientMock.Setup(x => x.Send(mail));

            // Create an instance of your MailSender class
            var mailSenderInstance = new CommunicationService(logger.Object, clientMock.Object);

            // Act
            var result = mailSenderInstance.SendMail(mailSender, recipients, cc, subject, mailContent, senderPass);



            
          
               Assert.IsTrue(result);


        }



Here is the unit test case, but it not work . Authentication unsuccessful message i am getting from the nunit test case.
```

Comment: if you just want the 'Send' method to succeed you can mock it using i.e. a Moq framework - there is another thread on mocking a method here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649228/how-to-mock-a-method-call-using-moq But you could probably rewrite your 'CommunicationService' so that it accepts an instance of SmtpClient (in constructor) and mock that one

Comment: But you could probably rewrite your 'CommunicationService' so that it accepts an instance of SmtpClient (in constructor) and mock that one , seen this suggestion in the stackoverflow and i have tried. But i couldnt succed with unit test case

Comment: I'll add some code

Comment: I'd *strongly* suggest abandoning .NET's deprecated SmtpClient and using the [alternative recommended in the .NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-7.0#remarks), [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit). MailKit's SmtpClient class inherits from `ISmtpClient` which makes mocking a *lot* easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your class like this and use SmtpClientWrapper in your production code:

```
 public interface ISmtpClient
 {
    void Send(MailMessage message);
 }

public class SmtpClientWrapper : ISmtpClient
{
    public SmtpClientWrapper(SmtpClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }

    public SmtpClient Client { get; }

    public void Send(MailMessage message)
    {
        Client.Send(message);
    }
}


public class CommunicationService: ICommunicationService 
{ 
    private readonly ILogger _logger; 
    private readonly ISmtpClient _client; 
    public CommunicationService( ILogger logger, ISmtpClient client) 
    { 
        _logger = logger;
        _client = client;
    }

     public bool SendMail(string mailSender, IEnumerable recipients, IEnumerable cc, string subject, string mailContent, string senderPass)
     {
          // validation part of the old method here
          
          // use client from constructor
          _client.Send(mailMessage);
     }
    }
```

Test method:

```
public void SendMail_SuccessfullySendsMail_ReturnsTrue()
    {
         // Arrange
            var clientMock = new Mock<ISmtpClient>();
            clientMock.Setup(x => x.Send(new MailMessage()));

            var mailSender = "your-email@example.com";
            var recipients = new List<string> { "recipient1@example.com", "recipient2@example.com" };
            var cc = new List<string> { "cc1@example.com", "cc2@example.com" };
            var subject = "Test Subject";
            var mailContent = "Test Body";
            var senderPass = "your-password";

            // Create an instance of your MailSender class
            var mailSenderInstance = new CommunicationService(logger.Object, smtpClient.Object);
        
            // Act
            var result = mailSenderInstance.SendMail(mailSender, recipients, cc, subject, mailContent, senderPass);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(result);

    }
```

There is also another thread on mocking the SmtpClient (which may provide more elegant solution): [How to mock/fake SmtpClient in a UnitTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971364/how-to-mock-fake-smtpclient-in-a-unittest)

Comment: Message: 
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.Send(mail)
Non-overridable members (here: SmtpClient.Send) may not be used in setup / verification expressions. ..i get this message

Comment: Updated my answer so that it uses interface and a wrapper class

Comment: Host = "smtp.office365.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = networkCredential,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    Timeout = 20000  How can i bind these properties in this case here

Comment: in your production code you would do: var smtp = new  SmtpClient{Host = "smtp.office365.com", Port = 587, EnableSsl = true, UseDefaultCredentials = false, Credentials = networkCredential, DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network, Timeout = 20000}; var wrapper = new SmtpClientWrapper (smtp); var service = new CommunicationService(null, wrapper);

Comment: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient' while attempting to activate 'xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.Email.SmtpClientWrapper'  getting this error while compiling

Comment: could succed the unit test case but some dependency is breaking while running.Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient' while attempting to activate 'xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.Email.SmtpClientWrapper' getting this error . can you plz help

Comment: @Bash could you please post your current code?

Comment: i have added the code... i still need to format the code

Comment: builder.Services.AddScoped<ISmtpClient, SmtpClientWrapper>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ICommunicationService, CommunicationService>();    I have added these dependencies also

Comment: you need to create and add an instance of SmtpClient as well: builder.Services.AddScoped<SmtpClient>((x) => { return new SmtpClient(); });

Comment: var service = new CommunicationService(null, wrapper); should i add this in the communication service... this was mentioned in the comment added by you... i am bit lost where it is needed...Now my compilation error is solved with the SmtpClient dependency...should it be in Addscoped only?

Comment: @Bash 'new CommunicationService(null, wrapper)' was just an example on how you can create an instance. But you are using dependency injection which will do it for you so it is not needed. PS: You could also AddSingleton (or what suits your needs) of SmtpClient but that depends on you. I do not know the whole use-case. Maybe check https://code-maze.com/dependency-injection-lifetimes-aspnet-core/

Comment: Unit test case expects the correct details...i get my unit test with error System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. Error: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Comment: can you see the code in communication service inside try block...did i made any mistake there

Comment: @Bash uncomment // clientMock.Setup(x => x.Send(mail)); in your test

Comment: it still fails with unit test case...

Comment: you also need to update your SendMail method because you are not using the injected object (of ISmtpClient type). Basically remove everything from the 'try-catch' and only leave '_client.Send(mailMessage);' from my example.

Comment: try  {
 var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "smtp.office365.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = networkCredential,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    Timeout = 20000
                };
                var wrapper = new SmtpClientWrapper(smtp);
                wrapper.Send(mailMessage);
               return true; }  here i call the Send from wrapper class.COrrect?

Comment: In that case where can i give the Port,host,Credentials etc

Comment: @Bash in your Program.cs

Comment: do you mean to add here while injecting the dependeny
  builder.Services.AddScoped<SmtpClient>((x) => { return new SmtpClient(); }) ;

Comment: @Bash exactly ;)